# Using Async Repository class is raising An Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have the following action method inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Deactivate(Staff staff)
{
  try
  {
    if (staff == null)
    {
      return Json(new { IsSuccess = "custome", id = 1, description = "Error occurred: Record has already been deleted." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    staffRepository.DeactivateStaff(staff);
    staffRepository.Save();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
}
```

and the following Repository classes:-

```
public void DeactivateStaff(Staff staff)
{
  staff.ISActive = false;
  context.Entry(staff).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

public async void Save()
{
  await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

and the following Abstract class:-

```
public interface IStaffRepository : IDisposable
{
  void Save();
  IQueryable<Staff> GetStaffForGrid(string filter, int page, int pageSize, string sort, string sortdir,bool isdeleted,bool isactive);
  int GetStaffForGridCount(string filter, bool isdeleted, bool isactive);
  SyncWithAD SyncUsersWithAD(string term = null);
  void DeactivateStaff(Staff staff);
  Task<Staff> FindStaff(int id,Byte[] timestamp);
}
```

now the following method inside the controller  `staffRepository.Save();`is raising the following exception:-

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous
>   operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or
>   module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this
>   exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is
>   marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>.

can anyone advise?

**EDIT**
my repository action methods are :-

```
public async Task DeactivateStaff(Staff staff)
              {

                  staff.ISActive = false;
                  context.Entry(staff).State = EntityState.Modified;

              }

            public async Task Save()
            {
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

my controller action method is :-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Deactivate(Staff staff)
        {
try
            {
                if (staff == null)
                { return Json(new { IsSuccess = "custome", id = 1, description = "Error occurred: Record has already been deleted." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }

                staffRepository.DeactivateStaff(staff);
               staffRepository.Save();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

currently i will get the following warning inside VS on the Deactivate method:-

> Warning   1   This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run
>   synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await
>   non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work
>   on a background thread

when i run my application and i call the action method , no exception will be raised by nothing will affect the database ? imean no update operation will be performed ,, can u adivce please?
Thanks

Comment: Do not use `async void ...` (http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/), make it return task...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) that describes the common causes of that error - one of which is `async void` methods. I have [another MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) that explains in detail why developers should avoid `async void`.

So, you just use `Task` instead of `void`. It's also a good idea to make your task-returning methods end in `Async`:

```
public interface IStaffRepository : IDisposable
{
  Task SaveAsync();
  ...
  Task<Staff> FindStaffAsync(int id, byte[] timestamp);
}
```

Implementation can remain the same:

```
public async Task SaveAsync()
{
  await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

or you can slightly simplify it:

```
public Task SaveAsync()
{
  return context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

and your controller method becomes `async`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Deactivate(Staff staff)
{
  try
  {
    ...

    staffRepository.DeactivateStaff(staff);
    await staffRepository.SaveAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you please check my "Edit" section inside my original question.. thanks as now i will not get any exception , but my code will not affect the Database..

Comment: Change your controller action to be `async` and `await` the call to `Save`, as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: you are correct, i modify the action method to be asynv with await and i got my changies saved to the DB ,, but not sure why it will not save to the DB unless i define async action method ?

Comment: @johnG: Most likely, your DB context is being disposed when the request completes. So if you don't (asynchronously) wait for the save to complete first, the context will be disposed, cancelling the save.

Comment: so i am starting to feel the danger of mixing sync with async code, i though i can mix both without any problem,, but seems on certain scenarios i will have problems? what do u think?

Comment: @johnG: Just follow the principle that anything that uses async code must itself be async.

Comment: yes i know , but technically speaking if i mix sync with async code this should not break the functionality. because sync & async deals with how IIS handles the requests, and does not have to do if IIS will skip some http requests and give priority to other http requests .. so even if i mix sync with async code i can be sure that IIS will serve the http request in the order i need as if i am using sync code only ? what do u think?

Comment: @johnG: I'm not sure what you're asking. IIS won't "skip" requests or change "priority". Sync-over-async or async-over-sync are scenarios that are *extremely* difficult to do right (and in some cases, impossible). However, you can have some entirely-sync actions and some entirely-async actions that coexist cleanly.

Comment: yes this what i am asking, so let say if i have an action method that find an object from the DB async using FindAsync() , then i modify some of the  object's proprties, then i save the object sync using .Save() instead of SaveChangesAsync() ? so will this cause any problems such as i have the .Save() executed before the .FindAsync() ?,,, i do not think so ? but need to conform ?

Comment: You *can* use an asynchronous `FindAsync` followed by a synchronous `SaveChanges` - it won't cause any problems, but there's no point in doing so.

Comment: yes i know ,, there is not any point ,, but i need to know this just in-case i miss write the code , so for example i use Save() instead of SaveAsyn() ,, with findAsyn(),,,